# Term for: Looking at someone like they're stupid

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, vocabulary

I'm writing something where on character looks at another character like they're stupid. Is there an adverb or something for that? For example: When the grown man asked his friends where babies come from they looked at him 'like he was stupid'. is there a word I can use to replace that?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. This is pretty open to interpretation, and may include a variety of facial expressions or emotional reactions. Different cultures, and even different generations have  ways of expressing disbelief.

Comment: I think Cascabel is correct, but all that is needed is an edit to your question to specify the culture, generation and attitude of the person.

Comment: "... like he was Donald Trump."

Answer (score 5):

*..they looked at him **incredulously***.

Excerpted from [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incredulously):

> **incredulous**
>
> unwilling to admit or accept what is offered as true :  not credulous :  skeptical
>
> - incredulously *adverb*

Answer (score 2):

They could be looking at their friend scornfully:

scorn: an expression of contempt or derision ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scorn))

They could be looking disdainfully or contemptuously. Disdain is to think unworthy of notice, response, etc.; consider beneath oneself ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/disdain)), and there's this definition of contempt from Merriam-Webster:  a feeling that someone or something is not worthy of any respect or approval ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contempt)).

Edited to add a link for that last definition, and to add:

Flabbergasted! I love that word. They could be flabbergasted: 
to overcome with surprise of bewilderment;astound. ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/flabbergasted))

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

[**Disdainfully**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disdain)

> Disdain: the feeling of not liking someone or something and thinking that they do not deserve your interest or respect.

[**Condescendingly**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/condescending)

> Condescending: treating someone as if you are more important or more intelligent than them